# Auto-detection application using Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I’ve got a question about use case of Ionic app.

Now I’m trying to create an application like this:

① Suppose you are a customer to go to a shop

② You have an auto-detect application installed on your mobile phone

③ Right after you enter the shop, the system in the shop detects you or the app in your phone automatically

④ You take some goods there and leave

⑤ The system in the shop detects you left the shop with the goods, and executes credit card payment automatically

I’m wondering if I can use ionic-native bluetooth library (BLE, BluetoothSerial) to implement auto-detection (③) while you have bluetooth on.

Is there any good way to realize such auto-detection using Ionic?